# Netty UDT examples on amazon ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, udp, netty, udp-data-transfer

I am not a networking guru so I am probably missing something simple.

I have built both the message echo client and msg echo server as runnable jar files using the netty 4.0.11 http://dl.bintray.com/netty/downloads/netty-4.0.11.Final.tar.bz2

I was able to load all of the correct dependencies using maven and the project builds and runs correctly locally and and on the server.  I can run a server on my local host and connect to it from a client on the same (localhost , both on my local machine and on my amazon ec2 instance.  Again it works connecting to itself (localhost) on both my machine, and my server computer.

THe problem is that I cannot connect to the server from outside the machine it is running, for example, I want to connect to my echo msg server (running on my ec2 instance) from the echo msg client running on my local computer.

I have setup the amazon security settings to allow UDP from the correct port and from the ip of my local machine.  I run the Echo server on the ec2 instance and it correctly starts up:

```
REGISTERED
ACTIVE 
DATAGRAM LISTENING bind=/0.0.0.0:1234 peer=null:0
```

But I just cannot connect from outside the local host, here is the error message I am getting from the client machine,
I have also turned off all firewalls (temporarily) on my local machine.  Still, when i try to connect I get:

```
CONNECT(/70.36.197.242:1234, null)
10:11:17.000 [connect-0] DEBUG com.barchart.udt.EpollUDT - ep 1 rem [id: 0x3287e50e] DATAGRAM CONNECTING bind=/0.0.0.0:55005 peer=null:0
10:11:17.000 [connect-0] DEBUG com.barchart.udt.EpollUDT - ep 1 add [id: 0x3287e50e] DATAGRAM CONNECTING bind=/0.0.0.0:55005 peer=null:0 ERROR_WRITE
10/24/13 10:11:19 AM ===========================================================
udt.echo.message.MsgEchoClientHandler:
  rate:
             count = 0
         mean rate = 0.00 bytes/s
     1-minute rate = 0.00 bytes/s
     5-minute rate = 0.00 bytes/s
    15-minute rate = 0.00 bytes/s

10:11:20.017 [connect-0] WARN  com.barchart.udt.nio.SelectionKeyUDT - logic error : 
[id: 0x3287e50e] poll=ERROR_WRITE ready=---- inter=-C-- DATAGRAM CONNECTOR CONNECTING bind=/0.0.0.0:55005 peer=null:0
java.lang.Exception: Unexpected error report.
    at com.barchart.udt.nio.SelectionKeyUDT.logError(SelectionKeyUDT.java:436) [barchart-udt-bundle-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.barchart.udt.nio.SelectionKeyUDT.doRead(SelectionKeyUDT.java:205) [barchart-udt-bundle-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.barchart.udt.nio.SelectorUDT.doResultsRead(SelectorUDT.java:334) [barchart-udt-bundle-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.barchart.udt.nio.SelectorUDT.doResults(SelectorUDT.java:309) [barchart-udt-bundle-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.barchart.udt.nio.SelectorUDT.doEpollExclusive(SelectorUDT.java:234) [barchart-udt-bundle-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.barchart.udt.nio.SelectorUDT.doEpollEnter(SelectorUDT.java:196) [barchart-udt-bundle-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at com.barchart.udt.nio.SelectorUDT.select(SelectorUDT.java:455) [barchart-udt-bundle-2.3.0.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.select(NioEventLoop.java:596) [netty-all-4.0.11.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:306) [netty-all-4.0.11.Final.jar:na]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101) [netty-all-4.0.11.Final.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_06]
10:11:20.018 [connect-0] DEBUG com.barchart.udt.EpollUDT - ep 1 rem [id: 0x3287e50e] DATAGRAM CONNECTING bind=/0.0.0.0:55005 peer=null:0
10:11:20.018 [connect-0] ERROR c.barchart.udt.nio.SocketChannelUDT - connect failure : [id: 0x3287e50e] DATAGRAM CONNECTING bind=/0.0.0.0:55005 peer=null:0
10:11:20.018 [connect-0] INFO  i.n.handler.logging.LoggingHandler - [id: 0x53f0f817] CLOSE()
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException
    at com.barchart.udt.nio.SocketChannelUDT.finishConnect(SocketChannelUDT.java:236)
    at io.netty.channel.udt.nio.NioUdtMessageConnectorChannel.doFinishConnect(NioUdtMessageConnectorChannel.java:132)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:228)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:502)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:417)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:101)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, after doing some more trouble shooting I found the solution. I had to in addition to allowing the port in the amazon  security settings, also allow the UDP port on the server firewall.